# Can I use GMail to load my IMAP emails and still have access to it directly along with GMail?

Tags: email, gmail, imap

I am trying to use my GMail as my web mail client and have it read my emails from my personal account (IMAP).

The problem is that I have both accounts configured on my iPhone, will this cause duplicate emails or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you're using two different e-mail accounts, I don't see how it would cause duplicate emails.

Comment: This personal account a Google Mail account?  You cannot configure Google Mail to check a third-party account as IMAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who provides your IMAP account? You may be able to set gmail up to download the messages by POP3, then they'd all be in your gmail with no duplicates...

Comment: I think that would be the only way to go about it is to have google download all my emails and use it as my primary webmail client. Thanks.